# Getting Client side Windows User ID in asp.net, for LDAP single sign on

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, impersonation

We have an existing webform that allows that uses form authentication that requires the user to key in id and pw to login to the system. Client requested that the program just take the username from the windows logged on username, and by this I mean the username used to login to the computer, not to the webpage.

Methods I have used to try to get the username:

```
    System.Environment.UserName;
    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    Context.User.Identity.Name;
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Windows Authentication(WA), Forms Authentication(FA), Basic Authentication(BA), Anonymous Authentication(AA), ASP.NET Impersonation (AI) have been enabled disabled in multiple different pairs. The suggestion I found the most were to enable (WA), disable (AA), enable (AI), but to no avail. The only thing that seems to affect the codes above is AI from my testing.

Enabling (AI) gives me:
NT AUTHORITY\IUSR

Disabling (AI) gives me:
IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated

Whereas what I am trying to get is MyDomain\MyUserName

I tried accessing the page from another computer that is not hosting it but still in the same domain and it gave me the same output. That lead me to suspect that the codes were giving me only the user that is running the process in the server, instead of the client side's Windows user.

My question is, does anyone have any idea how to get the username of the person logged in to the domain?

*Additional info: I'm using super user account in the domain, and providing the admin account and password to run visual studio as admin, if that somehow affects anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Windows authentication in IIS, and disable other authentication methods.

And make sure to set the authentication mode as "Windows" in `web.config`.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, tried that together with the IIS configuration, doesn't work.